# ActiveMQ Artemis - how does slave become live if there's only one master in the group?

Tags: high-availability, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to understand a couple of items relating to failover in the ActiveMQ Artemis documentation. Specifically, there is a section (I'm sure I'm reading it wrong) that seems as if it's impossible to for a slave to take over for a master:

> Specifically, the backup will become active when it loses connection to its live server. This can be problematic because this can also happen because of a temporary network problem. In order to address this issue, the backup will try to determine whether it still can connect to the other servers in the cluster. If it can connect to more than half the servers, it will become active, if more than half the servers also disappeared with the live, the backup will wait and try reconnecting with the live. This avoids a split brain situation

If there is only one other server, the master, the slave will not be able to connect to it. Since that is 100% of the other servers, it will stay passive. How can this work?

I did see that a pluggable quorum vote replication could be configured, but before I delve into that, I'd like to know what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using replication with only a single primary/backup pair there is no mitigation against split brain. When the backup loses its connection with the primary it will activate since it knows there are no other primary brokers in the cluster. Otherwise it would never activate, as you note.

The documentation should be clarified to remove this ambiguity.

Lastly, the documentation you referenced does not appear to be the most recent based on the fact that [the latest documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/ha.html#data-replication) is slightly different from what you quoted (although it still contains this ambiguity).

Generally speaking, a single primary/backup pair with replication is only recommended with the new pluggable quorum voting since the risk of split brain is so high otherwise.